# Display map from promise with emberJS and handlebars

Tags: ember.js, go, promise, handlebars.js

I am currently struggling to display maps in emberJS/handlebars (which is new for me).

Server side, I have a command.go file with:

```
var Actions = map[string]string{
    "EAT": "EAT.",
    "DRINK": "DRNK",
    "SLEEP": "SLP."
}
var Keys = map[string]int{
    "KEY_q": 0,
    "KEY_w": 1,
    "KEY_e": 2,
    ...
}
```

Each action and key have a string constant identifier and are associated to a string or int code.

I would like to display a 2 columns table in which:
- column 1 shows actions (like eat, drink, sleep, ...)
- column 2 shows a dropdown list with available keyboard keys (like Q, W, E, ...), their int code being the id of the  tag

I have a controller returning these maps as JSON object:

```
ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
    "actions":      models.Actions,
    "keys": models.Keys,
})
```

Then I a an emberJS service, config.js, as follows:

```
commands: computed(function () {
    return this.get('ajax').request('<address>/command').then(result => {
        return result;
    });
}),
commandActions: computed('commands', function() {
    return this.get('commands').then((commands) => {
        return commands.actions;
    });
}),
commandKeys: computed('commands', function() {
    return this.get('commands').then((commands) => {
        return commands.keys;
    });
}),
```

The controller commands.js is as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed, inject: { service } } = Ember;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    config: service(),

    selectedKey: '',

    actions: {
        selectKey(value) {

        },
    }
});
```

And finally in commands.hbs I have

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Associated key</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {{#each-in config.commandActions as |key value|}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{command}}</td>
          <td>
            {{#power-select
            options=config.commandKeys
            selected=selectedKey
            allowClear=false
            searchEnabled=false
            onchange=(action "selectKey")
            as |key|
            }}
              {{key}}
            {{/power-select}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      {{/each-in}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But nothing is displayed :(.
The service works well but then in the hbs file nothing appears. I have tried different combinations of each or each-in with no success.

Could someone please help?
Do I need to set variables in the controller somehow then use those variables in the hbs?

I'm using ember 2.5.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

The problem may come from the fact that I am trying to display a promise object before it is resolved. Any idea about that?

Comment: What do you see in developers console of a browser?

Comment: Nothing, the console is blank

Comment: (I'm assuming <address> is a placeholder to not show your real code). How have you verified the service is working?

Comment: I have tested `let res = commands; debugger;` and seen the result is fine and `res` does have the map with all keys and values

Comment: I think the issue is that #each doesn't know what to do with a promise. See this article: https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help you provided.

We finally managed to get what we wanted by doing the following:

In config.js service:

```
commands: computed(function () {
    return this.get('ajax').request('<address>/command').then(result => {
        return result;
    });
}),
```

In command.js controller:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

actions: computed(function() {
    return DS.PromiseArray.create({
        promise: this.get('config.commands').then((allCommands) => {
            let result = [];
            let actions = allCommands['actions'];

            for (var name in actions) {
                let cmd = Ember.Object.create({
                    'name': name,
                    'code': actions[name],
                });

                result.pushObject(cmd);
            }

            return result;
        })
    });
}),
```

Same code to get keys.

And in commands.hbs:

```
<tbody>
  {{#each actions as |action|}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{action.name}}</td>
      <td>
        {{#power-select
          options=keys
          selected=selectedKey
          allowClear=false
          onchange=(action 'selectKey' action)
          searchEnabled=false
          as |key|
        }}
          {{key.name}}
        {{/power-select}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Thanks again

Comment: Glad you got something working with a promise array and tweaking your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think with Ember Concurrency, your service will pause until your promise resolves, then return the results you want, rather than a promise object that `#each` doesn't know how to iterate over.

Your service code would end up looking like this:

```
commands: task(function*() {
  const allCommands = yield this.get('ajax').request('<address>/command');
  return allCommands;
}),
commandActions: computed.alias('commands.actions'),
commandKeys: computed.alias('commands.commandKeys')
```

and your template would be happy again.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, we get "regeneratorRuntime" error and the app crashes